# `estimator.train` with num_steps in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I have made a **custom estimator** in **Tensorflow 1.4**. In `estimator.train`function, I see a `steps` parameter, which I am using as a way to **stop** the training and then **evaluate** on my **validation dataset**.

```python
while True:
    model.train(input_fn= lambda:train_input_fn(train_data), steps = FLAGS.num_steps)
    model.evaluate(input_fn= lambda:train_input_fn(test_data))
```

After every `num_steps`, I run evaluate on **validation dataset**. 
What I am observing is, after `num_steps`, once the evaluation is done, there is a jerk in the plot of **AUC/Loss functions(in general all metric)**.

**Plot attached** : [image]

I am unable to understand why it's happening.

**Is it not the right way to evaluate `metrics` on `validation dataset` at regular intervals**

[Link to code](https://github.com/adakum/TF_Classification/blob/master/train_tf_II.py#L226-L229)

Comment: Maybe you could share a link to your full code to provide more information?

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot I have added the link to the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The issue

The issue comes from the fact that what you plot in TensorBoard is the accuracy or AUC computed since the beginning of `estimator.train`.

Here is what happens in details:

- you create a summary based on the second output of `tf.metrics.accuracy`

```py
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, predictions)
tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy[1])
```

- when you call `estimator.train()`, a new Session is created and all the local variables are initialized again. This includes the local variables of `accuracy` (sum and count)
- during this Session, the op `tf.summary.merge_all()` is called at regular intervals. What happens is that your summary is the accuracy of all the batches processed since you last called `estimator.train()`. Therefore, at the beginning of each training phase, the output is pretty noisy and it gets more stable once you progress.
- Whenever you evaluate and call `estimator.train()` again, the local variables are initialized again and you go in a short "noisy" phase, which results in **bumps** on the training curve.

---

### A solution

If you want a scalar summary that gives you the actual accuracy for each batch, it seems like you need to implement it without using `tf.metrics`. For instance, if you want the accuracy you will need to do:

```py
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(labels, predictions), tf.float32))
tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)
```

It is easy to implement this for the accuracy, and I know it might be painful to do for AUC but I don't see a better solution for now.

Maybe having these bumps is not so bad. For instance if you train on one epoch, you will get the overall training accuracy on one epoch at the end.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `tf.metrics.accuracy` maintains `sum` and `count` at aggregate level, i.e. whatever it has seen so far, right ?

Comment: Yes and the summary will plot that. There is no access to the current value for this batch.

Comment: Hey Olivier, I am trying to build a weighted binary classifier for a very skewed dataset. But the model is performing very weird (looking at the plots). I doubt if everything is fine in my script. Can u pls have a look man ? Would really appreciate that!